# How to get several specific records from a query result?

Tags: mysql

I know by using Like with "LIMIT 1, OFFSET x" I can get the Xth record from a returned query result. But what if I want to get X, Y, and Z all at once?

Currently I do a for loop and it's like I'm doing this:

```
SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET X

SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET Y

SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET Z
```

But I want something like this:

```
SELECT record from table LIMIT 3, OFFSET X, Y, and Z
```

This is because I think it is more efficient to get X, Y, Zth records in one query execution than in multiple ones.

Comment: Never use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. Unless you don't care about which rows are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET X
UNION
SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET Y
UNION
SELECT record from table LIMIT 1, OFFSET Z
```

Make them `UNION ALL` if you know that X,Y,Z are different or don't care if there are dups.  The default is `UNION DISTINCT`, which does an extra pass to dedup.

Comment: I just tried profiling using unions like this (using union all too). It was slow; individual queries would have been faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the X,Y,and Z are sequential you can use this:

```
SELECT record from table LIMIT X,3
```

Limit is not the best way of writing queries since it produces the entire query result set and send back only the number of rows specified (Version 5.5 MySQL). If you can use the primary key to look up the rows, include X,Y,and Z primary key in `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

> I know by using Like with "LIMIT 1, OFFSET x" I can get the Xth record from a returned query result

"Danger, Will Robinson!"

Rules #1 of Relational Databases: Rows in a table have *no intrinsic order*.

If you use "OFFSET" *without* an "ORDER BY" clause, there is *no guarantee* that you will always get the same results.